# How cut/slice the image into rectangular parts(with different sizes) as per data existed in that area in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, core-image, cgpath

I am working on iOS application.I need to take screenshots of any message application and have to edit like move and rearrange the messages in some order.In order to do that how to slice the image into pieces as shown in image? I save seen to cut the image into regular sizes but getting confused while working with different sizes.Please guide me if any one worked on it. It was achieved in [Longshot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/longshot-text-to-video-for/id891013264?mt=8) app.

Thanks in advance.
[image]